# String based error in basic algorithm for roman-numeral (using std::map)

Tags: c++, string, dictionary, data-structures, runtime-error

I am self-teaching myself data-structures using Malik's "Data Structures and Algorithm Desgin using c++". The first exercise is to make an object of type `numeralType` and encapsulate in it all the necessary operations to take in a string a return its value in the roman numeral system.

DISCALIMER 1: Please assume that there is data validation and everything is done except the function that converts the string into its value in the roman numeral system. Also, I am using VS17.

I will not post the original "conversion" function. Instead, I will post a generic version of the algorithm used in the function.

here it is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<map>


int main()
{
int result = 0;
std::map<char, int> charMap = { {'f',1},{'h',2},{'x',3},{'b',4},{'l',5} };
std::string testString = "lbxhf";
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < testString.length(); i++)
    {
        if (charMap.at(testString.at(i)) >= charMap.at(testString.at(i + 1)))
            result = charMap.at(testString.at(i)) + 
charMap.at(testString.at(i + 1));
    }
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

This code automatically calls `abort()` but compiles fine.

Using VS's debugger, i have singled out that the cause is string based, but I don't know exactly why.

Using a try/catch block I get that an `invalid string position` error. Here is the try/catch version:

```
int main()
{
    int result = 0;
    std::map<char, int> charMap = { {'f',1},{'h',2},{'x',3},{'b',4},{'l',5} };
    std::string testString = "lbxhf";

    try
    {

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < testString.length(); i++)
        {
            if (charMap.at(testString.at(i)) >= charMap.at(testString.at(i + 1)))
                result = charMap.at(testString.at(i)) + charMap.at(testString.at(i + 1));
        }
    }
    catch(const std::out_of_range& e) 
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I have been scratching my head around this for a whole day now and would like a few tips on how to solve this problem.

Again, this is a generic version of an algorithm that takes in a string of roman numerals and returns it value as an integer.

DISCLAIMER 2: This algorithm implies addition only, based on the rules of addition/subtraction of the roman numeral system.
DISCALIMER 3: it is important to me that I use std::map, I know it can be done using an array/vector type, but I also wish to practice using stl containers.

Thank you in advance (no need to be terribly mean guys!!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing `testString.at(i + 1)`, but `i` may be up to `testString.length()-1` because of the loop condition

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < testString.length(); i++)
```

This is the reason for the out-of-bounds exception. (`testString.length()-1` is the last index of `testString` and going one higher will be out-of-bounds.)

Not sure about your intentions, but maybe you want the loop condition to be

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i+1 < testString.length(); i++)
```

to only compare neighboring elements of the string.

Comment: this version of the for loop doesn't throw an exception, yes, but `result` should sum up to 15 and instead it sums up to 3, further debugging shows that for some reason, the characters of the string cannot be read :(

Comment: Well then your program logic is wrong. For example you are not actually adding to `result`, you are assigning it a new value each time the `if` condition is satisfied. I don't follow your intentions at all. Do you want to map each character to its integer value and then build the sum of those values?

Comment: yes, that's basically it, and i see what you mean! dammit!! haha if that is the case i may be able to solve the problem

Comment: Then what is the `if` condition supposed to be for? Just `result += charMap.at(testString.at(i));` as loop body would do.

Comment: in the roman numeral system, for example, lets say 'x' = 3 and 'b'=4. Now, the rules for addition and subtraction in that system state that if a larger numeral is placed before a smaller numeral, then that means addit-on (i.e "bx" = 7) otherwise, it means subtraction (i.e "xb" = 1)

Comment: The rules are actually more complicated, but if that is what you want you need to handle the last character specifically after your loop, because you cannot compare the last character to the one after that (which doesn't exist).

Comment: of course the rules are harder! I am only defining the sum of numerals in a sequential manner i.e the preceding numeral > proceding numeral, but yeah, the last character of the string has to handled, i noticed this when updating my code. I very much appreciate your input on this

Comment: What I mean is that you need to let the loop do all but the last character, then after the loop you write special code handling only the last character because the behavior for the last character must be different (there is no comparison to the next one).

Comment: I have got it to work! I have to see if what I have written is the best way to achieve my goal, but it's as you said, I had to used special code for the very last element in the string. I will go ahead to answer my own question! Thank you and happy new year!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with to solve the problem and achieve my goal:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<map>


int main()
{

    int result = 0;
    std::map<char, int> charMap = { {'f',1},{'h',2},{'x',3},{'b',4},{'l',5} };
    std::string testString("lbxhf");
    char lastChar = testString.back();
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i+1 < testString.length(); i++)
    {
        if(charMap.at(testString.at(i)) >= charMap.at(testString.at(i+1)))
            result += charMap.at(testString.at(i));
    }
    result += charMap.at(lastChar);
    printf("%i\n", result);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```